# How to prevent IE from converting textarea newlines to a single space

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, newline

I have the following HTML code, which essentially copies a textarea box, including its text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function copyTextarea() {
                var originalTextbox = document.getElementById('originalTextarea');
                var copiedTextboxSpan = document.getElementById('copiedTextareaSpan');

                var text = originalTextbox.value;

                copiedTextboxSpan.innerHTML = '<textarea name="myNewTextarea" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>';

                var newTextbox = document.getElementsByName('myNewTextarea')[0];
                newTextbox.innerHTML = text;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Enter your text:
        <br />
        <textarea id="originalTextarea" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Copy Textarea" onclick="copyTextarea()" />
        <br />
        Copied text:
        <br />
        <span id="copiedTextareaSpan"></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a very simplified version of HTML I have, so please don't suggest huge changes. I need to create the textarea box and set its text separately, etc.

This code seems simple and works fine, except when it comes to newline characters. For some reason, Internet Explorer (IE) always converts newlines into a single space. Stranger still, this was not happening locally on my Tomcat server, but crept up when I deployed to the test server. But on the test server, it is working fine in Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Does anyone know what might be happening? I don't know too much about JavaScript, but I think it's the browser that executes the code. But if that is true, why does IE have no problems locally but has a problem on the test server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating actual DOM objects:

```
newTextarea = document.createElement('textarea');
newTextarea.setAttribute('name', 'myNewTextarea');
newTextarea.setAttribute('rows', '5');
newTextarea.setAttribute('cols', '50');

copiedTextboxSpan.appendChild(newTextarea);

var newTextbox = document.getElementsByName('myNewTextarea')[0];
newTextbox.value = text;
```

Also, use `value` instead of `innerHTML` when dealing with a textarea.

Comment: No luck. Strangely enough, IE is now not even copying over the text. It works fine locally, but on the server it has a JavaScript error complaining about 'undefined' when trying to set the new textarea value. I put in some alerts. On the server, IE says that `getElementsByName` returns a `[object]`, while locally it says it returns a `[object HTMLCollection]`. Meanwhile, Chrome on the server says it's a `[object NodeList]`

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is, in that case. If you were using jQuery, it normalizes the browser inconsistencies quite well. I can help rewrite your code if you do use it, as it is literally a few lines.

Comment: I don't know jQuery. I tried `$('textarea[name=myNewTextarea]').val(text);`, but the text did not get displayed. Is there something wrong?

Comment: I didn't change anything to my original code except replace the last 2 lines with that `$('textarea[name=myNewTextarea]').val(text);`.

Comment: I actually got the text to copy over. For some reason, jQuery isn't being recognized on my test page but is on my real page. However, newlines are now being replaced with `%0A`. Does jQuery have an easy way to escape/unescape?

Comment: Probably the missing `http:` in the `src` of the script tag. This new code should be better: http://jsfiddle.net/4q5ed/4/. As for your question, where are you seeing `%0A`? In the server?

Comment: I managed to get jQuery to work on the test page. And the jQuery code successfully copied over the newlines (on the server). Sadly, it is still not working on my real page. But I think that might have something to do with Struts. So I'll need to investigate that. But you helped fixed the test page. +1. Thanks for all the help. =)

Comment: No problem. Once you get used to jQuery, writing JS code is a lot easier

Comment: The "Head First jQuery" book is on my Xmas list. So hopefully my life will get easier soon. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with jQuery:

```
$('#copiedTextareaSpan').replaceWith(function () {
    var text = $('#originalTextarea').val();
    return '<textarea name="myNewTextarea" rows="5" cols="50">' + text + '</textarea>';
});
```

copies the text from `originalTextarea` to `copiedTextArea` (after creating it).